# Google Script function returns blank output

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Using the following code to return a portion of a string:

```
function myFunction() {  
    var str = "";  
    var res = str.substr(44, 47);  
    Logger.log(res)   
return res 
}
```

When I go to use the function in a spreadsheet, it returns a blank. There is no error message associated. What do I need to change to return the portion of the string I am trying to isolate?

Comment: Jut a guess, but what if you `return res` instead of `return myFunction`? I don't know Google Scripts really well, but I'm not sure what the point here is of having the function return itself instead of the string value `res`.

Comment: I hope you are aware of the effects of returning the name of the function itself  ?

Comment: return res results in the same blank output

Answer (score 1):

Your str is empty ,so you are returning an empty string.  If you try the following, as a comparison, a substring is returned:

```
function myFunction() {  
    var str = "This is a string which is longer than forty seven characters long so it should give some output";  
    var res = str.substr(44, 47);  
    Logger.log(res)   
return res 
}
```